# How to control opening and closing of the turtle graphics window?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am writing a program for generating images using the python turtle graphics module. Is there a way to control when the window opens and closes? I know that `turtle.bye()` and `turtle.exitonclick()` close the window, but then it is problem to open it again.

Currently I open the window just by assigning `turtle.Turtle()` to a variable like this:

```
t = turtle.Turtle()
```

I looked in documentation and also here but I didn't find anything.

Comment: What's supposed to happen while it's closed? In other words: What's the purpose of being able to do this?

Comment: When it's closed, the code's supposed to continue. I want to generate images based on console input and I'd want it to open after input, draw the image and close after viewing. I think it'll be easiest to use it this way.

Comment: `turtle` graphics is built on top of Python's `tkinter` module, which is for GUI programming. This means you'll first need to devise some way of terminating the `mainloop()` that's running when graphics are being displayed. The only way I can see to do that is by providing a callback function to handle some kind of user input event, such as the pressing of a certain key or clicking the mouse somewhere. Is that acceptable, and if so, what should it be? I suppose you could also run a `turtle`-based script as a separate process, but doing so would require some relatively advanced programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something demonstrating how to hide and redisplay the turtle-graphics window without requiring user input to do so. It uses the tkinter [`after()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method to schedule a future call to the function I've named `do_turtle_stuff()` (if you're interested).

It accomplishes this by "reaching under the covers" and getting the underlying `tkinter` root window and manipulating it. To allow the user to execute several "commands" it reschedules itself to run gain by making a call to `after()` itself (unless the user typed in "exit"). You may not need to that for what you're doing.

```
import turtle


def do_turtle_stuff(root):
    user_input = input('Enter command ("foo", "bar", or "exit"): ')

    if user_input == "exit":
        root.withdraw()  # Hide the turtle screen.
        root.quit()  # Quit the mainloop.
        return
    elif user_input == "foo":
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(100)
    elif user_input == "bar":
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(100)
    else:
        print('Unknown command:', user_input)

    root.after(0, lambda: do_turtle_stuff(root))


root = turtle.getscreen()._root
root.after(0, lambda: do_turtle_stuff(root))
root.mainloop()

print('back in main')
input('Press Enter key to do more turtle stuff ')

root.state('normal')  # Restore the turtle screen.
root.after(0, lambda: do_turtle_stuff(root))
root.mainloop()

print('done')
```

Comment: VectorSVK: Thanks. Although it doesn't show how to open and close turtle-graphics windows, I think you might find the `TurtleShell` [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html#cmd-example) in the [`cmd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html#module-cmd) module's documentation interesting.